# Hover effect of stretched link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use this code in Bootstrap 4. All I need is change background-color of .card element but it don't work if I use stretched-link.

Can you help me with solution?

```css
.card:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card bg-light wow fadeIn position-relative">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <p>Caption</p>
        <a href=".." class="stretched-link"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add !important after your value and it will work.

```
.card:hover {
      background-color: blue !important;
    }
```

```css
.card:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card bg-light wow fadeIn position-relative">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <p>Caption</p>
        <a href=".." class="stretched-link"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```